# How to getText() like input[i][j].getText(); (for sudoku solver in netbeans)

Tags: java, text, netbeans, field, sudoku

I want to get the text in `int` form from 81 text fields arranged in a `9 X 9`grid but don't want to do it individually. I tried to put it in a loop but the problem is that the text field name has to be shown in `a[i][j]` form.

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        a[i][j] = *i want the name of text field like "a" + i + j*.getText(); 
    }
}
```

The text fields are name like:

> a00, a01, a02, a03, a04 ... a88.

Comment: 1. In Java, arrays are 0 based, meaning that your loops need to start from 0 keep going till the counter is *less* than 9. Your current code will result into an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. 2. I am not sure I am following, but do to what you are after you could do `a[i][j] = "a" + String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(j);`.

Comment: I actually changed you code in the edit: I removed wrong semicolons and made everything 0 based, in order for it not to distract from what I consider the essence of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with java (actually there are ways of doing that, but they are complicated, error prone and most certainly not what you want. If you still want to know, look up reflection).

The solution to your problem is to make the 81 text boxes an array of text boxes

```
JTextField[][] input = new JTextField[9][9];
for(i=0;i<9;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<9;j++) {
        input[i][j] = new JTextField(); 
    }
}
```

Now you can adress each by

```
input[x][y]
```

with x and y being integers between 0 and 8 inclusive.

Especially you can do

```
input[x][y].getText()
```

To get the value from a single input field.

Comment: Also add a point on how to `getText()` like `input[i][j].getText();`

Comment: I did what you said and it's not showing any errors. but its not working either. it just stays there. no output.

Comment: In the code you posted (and mine as well) there is no statement that generates output, so this is no surprise to me. This really sounds like a different question, since your original is answered as far as I can tell. So go ahead and create a new question including the source code relevant to that question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a String to a variable like

`"a" + i + j.getText();`

You need to change your textfields's to something like which Jens specified.

If you don't want to change all your textfields, you need to add references for them which is not at all recommended.

```
JTextField [][]fields = new JTextField[9][9];
fields[0][0] = a00;
fields[0][1] = a01;
fields[0][2] = a02;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

A) Store your text fields in a `JTextField[][]` array.

B) Use reflection

Since `A` is already explained in other answers, I'll only focus on `B`.

[Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) in Java can be used to transform name of some field to the field itself, sort of.

```
JTextField getField(int row, int col) {
    int index = 9 * col + row; // for row-major tables
    // int index = 9*row + col; // for col-major tables

    String name = String.format("a%02d", index);
    System.out.println("Name: " + name); //For debugging purposes

    try {
        Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField(name);

        return (JTextField) field.get(this);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException
            | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

You will need to put this code to the same class that have `a00, a01, a02, ...` fields declared. Also this will only **get** the `JTextField` that is stored in your field, so you can't use this to **set** the fields. Sililar set method could be used for that.

However, using reflection in Java is generally considered a bad practice. Here, solution `A` can and should be used, but if you are lazy and you don't want to rewrite your code, you can use this.