# No error yet no output. Help.(Sudoku solver getter)

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, sudoku, solver

I want to add text fields `a01, a02, ...` to the array `a`.
I want to display the value of `val` so that I would know if the text is being taken from text fields. This code does not show any errors, but, well, it doesn't give me output as well.

```
int i, j;

JTextField[][] a = new JTextField[9][9];

int[][] val = new int[9][9];

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        val[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(a[i][j].getText());
        System.out.println(val[i][j]);
    }
}
```

It is from my old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111712/how-to-gettext-like-inputij-gettext-for-sudoku-solver-in-netbeans).

Comment: Are you sure the execution reaches the for loop? Can you put a minimal but **complete** code to repro the problem?

Comment: It is normal array initialization problem which you should be aware of

Answer (score 5):

You did not give them value

```
int i,j; // counter
JTextField[][] a = new JTextField[9][9];
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        tf.setText("a"+i+j);
        a[i][j] = tf;
    }
}
```

In your version the call to `a[i][j].getText()` should throw a NullPointerException. This should either kill your application, end up on the console or you have somewhere something like

try { 
       // more code here
   } catch (Exception ex){}

which will silently swallow the exception and is veeeeery bad practice.

Comment: Indeed, the OP only created an array of JTextFields without initializing it. Still, I find it surprising that he didn't get a NullPointerException when attempting to access the uninitialized text fields.

Comment: That means he try catch-ed or init them but did not paste here

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown us *does* generate an error - it throws a `NullPointerException` when you try to access the text of the text fields via `a[i][j].getText()`.

You didn't initialize the `JTextFields` in your array `a`.

[ideone example](https://ideone.com/JIWfVr)